# how to delete a db line by pressing button delete with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function that when a field is empty i can delete the line in database e when there is something send an error msg.

```js
public function deleteConfig() {
        if ($_POST['Doc'] != '') {
            $todelete = array();
            $todelete['domd_tipol_doc'] = $_POST['type_protocol'];
            $this->model->delete('domc', $todelete);
        } else {
            echo "error!";
        }
    }
```

Now i have this ajax call that when someone press the delete button call the php function.
I cant understand what i have to do in the 'something to do here to get what I want

```js
$('.btn-delete-config').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'protocol/deleteConfig'
        }).done(function( data ) {
            //SOMETHING TO DO HERE
        });

    });
```

Comment: //SOMETHING TO DO HERE is what you do on the clientside? what do you want to do? remove something from the page?

Comment: I want to remove all the page where i press the delete button

Comment: What do you mean "remove all the page"? Do you want to re-direct to another page? Do you want to re-load the same page?

Comment: Well it is impossible for us to help you without knowing anything about hor page and what is supposed to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to have more code. But generally you have to remove everything that is in the DOM that serves everything. to do this, you have to call a `$(this).closest('DOMELEMENT').remove()` on the dom you want to remove. For example:

```js
$('.btn-delete-config').click(function() {
       var button = $(this);
       //I can't reproduce the ajax. Put the following inside the .done function
       button.closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td><button class="btn-delete-config">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```